# Why is my code not copying text correctly when an equation in involved? (Excel Macro/Visual Basic)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

In Excel, I altered some code to automatically copy text of a pre-selected range into a .txt file when the Command Button is clicked.  For some reason, whenever this code attempts to copy from cells that have an =IF(AND( __, __ ), __, __) statement in it, it will not take the text, however it works perfectly fine for text that is simply entered into the cell with no form of equation. Also, the first few cells in the column are plain text without any equations, so having the equation in the code itself will not be desirable. What can I do to my code so it will not alter the information copied from Excel cells containing an equation referencing other cells? Code is exactly as seen below. Also, I am working in Excel 2007. Thank you!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim saveFile As String
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set WorkRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B25").Copy
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
wb.Worksheets(1).Paste
saveFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
wb.SaveAs Filename:=saveFile, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
wb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Comment out the "on error resume next" - do you get an error?

Comment: Yes. "run-time error '424': Object Required"  When I clicked debug, it highlighted the "Set WorkRng..." line.

Comment: So I have to set an Object?

Comment: Your error is because .Copy is not a functino (i.e. it does not return a range). You have no need to assign to WorkRng. Simply use the statement `Activeblahblah.Copy`

Comment: The `.Copy` method does not return an object - you should remove that.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim saveFile As String
    Dim WorkRng As Range

    Set WorkRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B25") '<<no .Copy    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add

    'WorkRng.Copy wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1") 

    'copy values only
    WorkRng.Copy
    wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    saveFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
    wb.SaveAs Filename:=saveFile, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
    wb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Hits the issues +1. There is an unlikely but possible edge case that is perhaps worth sticking in Application.Calculate after the copy paste as if Manual calculation is the current mode (set by user in gui or code, and I have seen it several times particularly with large cluncky inefficient workbooks where the user has given up on automatic calculation) then the formuale won't evaluate before the export.

Comment: The above change returns the same value as the original code.

Comment: @Pika2u - care to expand?  Are you saying you're still getting an error?  If so, maybe you can add more details on the exact formulas which aren't getting copied correctly.

Comment: @Tim Williams - The equation in cell A2 is =IF(AND(D2=1,$G$5=1), $F$8, $G$8).  This continues down the column for a ways with B2 increasing proportionate to D2. The value of $G$5 is 1 in this particular trial.  $F$8 is always 0111011000 and $G$8 is always 0000000100. The value of D2 switches between 1 and 0.  So basically its a wave.  Using your revised code above, the text returned in the text file displays the same numbers for all the data (row 2 - row 50 or whatever), even though it should be osculating between the two sets of numbers, as it does on the actual excel sheet.

Comment: Put a break on the line `saveFile=...` and run your code (also comment out the screenupdating line).  You can see that all of your copied ColA cells are zero, and this is what you'd expect, since as soon as you paste to the other sheet it will calculate, and on that sheet there's nothing in Columns D, F or G...  See my edit above to just copy the values

Comment: It works perfectly now. Completely fixed. Thank you!